# Image disappears if not directly centered in window [Margin not "0"]

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I've got a bit of a problem with my images in a WPF Vb.net based window.
If the image control is not directly in the centre of the window with a margin of 0, it will not show at runtime.

Here is the XAML code for both images:

```
    <Image x:Name="loaderlogo" Height="55" Margin="1825,985,40,40" Width="55" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <Image x:Name="tips" Height="128" Margin="0,732,0,220" Width="1920" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.9"/>
```

Both are contained inside a grid with one row and one column (the default grid that is there when you create a new window).

These images will not appear if this code is run however if i make the margins

```
Margin="0"
```

They will appear just fine, but in the very center of the control

How can i make it so that the controls still appear if the margins are not zero (if i move the images' location anywhere but the center of the form?

The code i use to fetch the image files is:

```
    UseLayoutRounding = True
    Dim exepath As String = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    loaderlogo.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri(exepath & "loaderlogo.png", UriKind.Absolute))
    tips.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri(exepath & "tips.png", UriKind.Absolute))
```

The images work perfectly fine if dead center so I believe the problem is with the XAML but I am not sure where. I have changed the horizontal/vertical alignment but the images still appear in the center as long as the margin is 0.

EDIT: Below are the positions where I would like the controls to be, the bottom left is the 'loaderlogo' and the band across the window is the 'tips' control.

[tips band position](https://imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/02/28/position1.jpg)

[loaderlogo position](https://imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/02/28/position2.jpg)

EDIT 2: Below is the entire XAML code for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="loadingwindow" UseLayoutRounding="True"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:applicationname"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="loadingwindow" Height="1080" Width="1920" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Completed="DoubleAnimation_Completed"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>

</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="loaderlogo" Height="55" Margin="1825,985,40,40" Width="55" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <Image x:Name="tips" Height="128" Margin="0,732,0,220" Width="1920" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.9"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: the solution depends on how you need to position images. where should they be? screenshot maybe

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @ASh . I've added screenshots of the position images to the original post.

Comment: Please post your entire Window XAML.

Comment: I've added the window XAML to the original post. Thanks for your reply @KellyBarnard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Large margins are the worst way to position elements. The better approach is to use correct layout panel and correct alignments for elements. Small margin is fine to add some space between elements.

`Grid` panel is usually used with many `RowDefinition`s and `ColumnDefinition`s. Elements are placed in different rows and columns, and resulting layout is adaptive to size changes

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Image x:Name="tips" Grid.Row="1" Height="128" Width="1920" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.9"/>
  <Image x:Name="loaderlogo" Grid.Row="2" Height="55" Width="55" Margin="10"
         HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much @ASh !